# How to use python with "pyreportjasper" to convert from "jrxml" (with database) to "pdf"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jasper-reports, pyreport

I've a ".jrxml" file created by TIBCO Jaspersoft. I follow this link https://pypi.org/project/pyreportjasper/ to convert from ".jrxml" to ".pdf" by using Python . It seems work just fine when I was not using a database.

I did "Compiling" and "Processing" topic and it works just fine, but I stuck on a topic named "Advanced example - using a database". The code is below.

```py
from platform import python_version
import pyreportjasper


def advanced_example_using_database():
    input_file = 'C:/Users/CPM-USER/JaspersoftWorkspace/SCPS_TEST/test1.jrxml'
    output = 'C:/Users/CPM-USER/Desktop'
    con = {
        'driver': 'mysql',
        'username': 'root',
        'password': 'root',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database': 'icontrol_cscs_prj',
        'port': '3306'
    }
    print(python_version())
    jasper = pyreportjasper.JasperPy()
    jasper.process(
        input_file,
        output_file=output,
        format_list=["pdf"],
        # parameters={'python_version': '3.7.4'},
        db_connection=con,
        locale='en_US'  # LOCALE Ex.:(en_US, de_GE)
    )


advanced_example_using_database()
```

It cause an error "Unable to load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you do not have the mysql driver in java classpath.

You need first to download the driver http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Then according to pyreportsjasper [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyreportjasper/#description) you need to place the .jar in the

```
pyreportjasper/jasperstarter/jdbc/
```

directory.

Comment: Would it be possible to place .jar in another specific directory?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just found that .jar directory can be changed by defining `'jdbc_dir'` from db_connection in 'pyreportjasper.JasperPy().process'

Comment: @KritkornSupyen great find!